# IOS. Sharing image to Instagram without using a menu display

Tags: ios, instagram-api

Can anyone help and explain how to do sharing to Instagram without displaying the menu? For example, the application Prisma does it without using a menu display.

Comment: By menu do you mean UIActivityController?

Comment: I mean UIDocumentInteractionController.

Comment: Some how I am not able to access this instagram doc here which has related info https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/# . You can search for "iPhone Instagram Hooks" for more.

Comment: Thanks, but I am familiar with this instruction, that's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You must do this:

1. Save your photo to photo library
2. Take asset url of saved photo
3. Open Instagram through URL Scheme with this URL

> instagram://library?AssetPath=ASSET_PATH

Where ASSET_PATH is asset url taken on the second step.

Code example on **Swift 3**:

```
let library = ALAssetsLibrary()
library.writeImage(toSavedPhotosAlbum: image.cgImage, metadata: nil) { (url, error) in
    if let url = url {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let path = url.absoluteString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)
            let instagram = URL(string: "instagram://library?AssetPath=\(path)")
            UIApplication.shared.open(instagram!)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old questions but I just wanted to provide an updated answer for those who may be looking.

Vitaly Berg has the right approach just with deprecated code. Here is up to date code (Swift 5) That worked for me:

```
@IBAction func instagramButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {

            //check and see if we can save photos
            let status = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
            if (status == PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
                // Access has been granted.
                self.shareToInstagram(theImage!)
            }else if (status == PHAuthorizationStatus.denied) {
                // Access has been denied.
                Notifications.showNotification("Please Allow Access To Photos To Share", style: .danger)
            }else if (status == PHAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined) {
                // Access has not been determined.
                PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({ (newStatus) in
                    if (newStatus == PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
                        self.shareToInstagram(theImage!)
                    }else {
                        Notifications.showNotification("Please Allow Access To Photos To Share", style: .danger)
                    }
                })
            }else if (status == PHAuthorizationStatus.restricted) {
                // Restricted access - normally won't happen.
                Notifications.showNotification("Please Allow Access To Photos To Share", style: .danger)
            }
}


func shareToInstagram(_ theImageToShare: UIImage){
    self.saveToCameraRoll(image: theImageToShare) { (theUrl) in
        if let url = theUrl {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let path = url.absoluteString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed){
                    let instagram = URL(string: "instagram://library?AssetPath=\(path)")
                    UIApplication.shared.open(instagram!)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


func saveToCameraRoll(image: UIImage, completion: @escaping (URL?) -> Void) {
    var placeHolder: PHObjectPlaceholder? = nil
    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        let creationRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: image)
        placeHolder = creationRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset!
    }, completionHandler: { success, error in
        guard success, let placeholder = placeHolder else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: [placeholder.localIdentifier], options: nil)
        guard let asset = assets.firstObject else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        asset.requestContentEditingInput(with: nil, completionHandler: { (editingInput, _) in
            completion(editingInput?.fullSizeImageURL)
        })
    })
}
```

Hope this helps someone!