# How to directly share an image to instagram?

Tags: ios, swift, instagram

I have seen answers to how to share to instagram. The problem is that I am unable to share ***DIRECTLY*** to insta. Currently when I run this code I get a thing for sharing come up from the bottom and see ***Copy to Instagram*** when I tap then it opens insta and I can share. But I would like to skip this step like I have seen in other apps. **How can I do this?**

My current code for this:

```
                 let instagramURL = URL(string: "instagram://app")
                if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(instagramURL!) {
                    if let url = Auth.auth().currentUser?.photoURL {
                        let image = self.getImage(url: url)
                        let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)//UIImage.jpegData(image)
                        let writePath = (NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString).appendingPathComponent("instagram.igo")
                        do {
                            try imageData!.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: writePath), options: .atomic)
                            //try imageData.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: writePath), options: .atomic)
                        } catch {
//                            print(error)
                        }

                        let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: writePath)
                        self.documentController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: fileURL)
                        self.documentController.delegate = self
                        self.documentController.uti = "com.instagram.exlusivegram"

                        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
                            self.documentController.presentOpenInMenu(from: self.view.bounds, in: self.view, animated: true)
                        }
//                        else {
//                            self.documentController.presentOpenInMenu(from: self.IGBarButton, animated: true)
//                        }
                    } else {
                        let imageData = UIImage(named: "media")!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)//UIImage.jpegData(image)
                        let writePath = (NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString).appendingPathComponent("instagram.igo")
                        do {
                            try imageData!.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: writePath), options: .atomic)
                        } catch {
//                            print(error)
                        }

                        let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: writePath)
                        self.documentController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: fileURL)
                        self.documentController.delegate = self
                        self.documentController.uti = "com.instagram.exlusivegram"

                        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
                            self.documentController.presentOpenInMenu(from: self.view.bounds, in: self.view, animated: true)
                        }
//                        else {
//                            self.documentController.presentOpenInMenu(from: self.IGBarButton, animated: true)
//                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: The official way to share via Instagram is using the Document Interaction API.  That's what it looks like you're doing.  You won't be able to post content on behalf of the user or at least posting without the user giving permission from their sharing workflow.

Comment: @Derek Im not trying to share for them, I only want to skip the step where u have to choose insta, the user already chose it so i would like to open it up with the image directly

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38303413/ios-sharing-image-to-instagram-without-using-a-menu-display)?

Comment: @SoroushShahi trying it now

Comment: @SoroushShahi Worked!

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution here: [IOS. Sharing image to Instagram without using a menu display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38303413/ios-sharing-image-to-instagram-without-using-a-menu-display)

As **Soroush Shahi** said in the comments